# FrameLayout.addView() on Mockito spy object adds view to mChildren, but mChildrenCount is still 0

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I encountered a problem when using `Mockito.spy()` method.

I am writing a unit test to add indifferent (it doesn't matter if it's a real view, or a mock) view  to Mockito spy object of `FrameLayout` in a following way:

```
// given
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
FrameLayout spy = spy(frameLayout);

// when
spy.addView(mock(View.class));

// then
Assert.assertEquals(1, spy.getChildCount());
```

**This test fails**, because `spy.getChildCount()` returns 0. Indeed, while previewing on debug I see:

[image: wrong]

**Since `mChildren` contains my view, why `mChildrenCount` is not updated with value of 1?**

---

To comparison, following test without spying passes:

```
// given
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(RuntimeEnvironment.application);

// when
frameLayout.addView(mock(View.class));

// then
Assert.assertEquals(1, frameLayout.getChildCount());
```

with expected debug preview:

[image: right]

I am using `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`. I made up a sample project [here on GitHub](https://github.com/kotomoto/mockito-testing) illustrating my problem.

Comment: No solution here?